# Use teradata datasource in websphere distributed transaction

Tags: java, websphere, datasource, teradata, xa

I want to use teradata data source in global transaction in websphere 9.0 along with oracle XA datasource.
I am trying to figure out how to setup teradata as XA datasource, is there specific implementation class similar to oracleConnectionpooldatasource vs oracleXAdatasource? Do we have an equivalent XA datasource implemenation for TeraConnectionPoolDataSource? Is there connection pool property we can set?

Thanks

Comment: The Teradata database engine has some support for 2PC, but that mode is not available with the Teradata JDBC driver. It is primarily used with mainframe applications having IBM's Transaction Server (CICS) or IMS/DC as the transaction manager.

Answer (score 1):

The [Teradata JDBC Driver Reference](https://teradata-docs.s3.amazonaws.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/jdbcug_chapter_4.html#BABEFFIG) documents only TeraConnectionPoolDataSource (which implements javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource) and TeraDataSource (which implements javax.sql.DataSource). This leads me to believe that they do not provide an implementation of javax.sql.XADataSource.

That said, it is possible in WebSphere Application Server, at the cost of certain trade-offs, to have a data source which doesn't implement javax.sql.XADataSource participate in a global transaction alongside two-phase commit capable resources (such as the Oracle XADataSource).  To do this, you must be willing to accept the possibility that if an outage or other interruption occurs after the point where the two-phase resources have completed the prepare phase when the one-phase resource (TeraData in this case) is told to commit/roll back, then the transaction manager will not know the outcome of the one-phase resource, and will be unable to automatically determine the outcome during XA recovery, such that resolution of the transaction will require manual intervention.  This capability is often referred to as "Last Participant Support" (due to placement of the one-phase resource as the last resource after all of the all of the two-phase resources complete the prepare phase), and is also referred to as "Accept Heuristic Hazard" (due to the situation described earlier in this response where there is uncertain outcome).